# sphinx query on NOT array

Tags: ruby, sphinx

I can't find example for my task

I have an array of strings and I need to make query to retrieve all rows that DON'T contain every string from the array

building string like this 
(!11 !22 !33) doesn't work (single NOT operator)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really do need to do that, need to include a term that will match every row.

eg you could arrange for 99 to be present on every single row.

```
(99 !11 !22 !33)
```